# Can't find proper value to use without getting for insert function

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list

I've been coding for a few hours today but seem to have thrown a blank. The assignment is creating a grocery list and adding in certain items to it while checking to see if the item is already in the list, if the list is empty and other things.

While working on the assignment, I can't find the proper value/variable to use in my insert function and it's killing me that something this small has stopped me from doing the assignment. The error is in my GroceryList.cpp file where all the functions are defined and all the code written out so that it removes, inserts, and checks for empty list. Everything else seems to compile just fine so far (I still need to fix some functions) but right now I'm trying to get my insert function to work. Can anyone look over my code and point me in the right direction for which value to use in my insert function? Did I even write the insert function properly? Thanks.

GroceryList.h

```
#ifndef GROCERYLIST_H
#define GROCERYLIST_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace CS151GroceryList
{

// node definition
struct ListNode
{
    string item;
    ListNode *link;
};

// define a type for pointers to nodes
typedef ListNode* ListNodePtr;

// define the GroceryList class
class GroceryList
{
public:

    // default constructor initializes an empty list
    GroceryList();

    // destructor - destroys the list and returns all memory to the heap
    ~GroceryList();

    // returns true if the list is empty; false otherwise
    bool empty();

    // check to see if an item is in the list.  If so, return true.  If not, return false.
    bool inList(const string& an_item);

    // prints all of the items in the list.  If insert is implemented correctly, the contents
    // of the list will be printed in alphabetical order with no repeats.
    void print();

    // if an_item is found, remove it from the list
    void remove(const string& an_item);

    // put a new item into the list.  The item should be placed into the correct
    // position in the list.  If the item is already in the list, no change is
    // made to the list.  Note, you should put A COPY of an_item into the list
    void insert(const string& an_item);


private:
    ListNodePtr top;
};


} // end CS151GroceryList namespace

#endif GROCERYLIST_H
```

GroceryListTest.cpp      **This test the functions to make sure they work. Adds in specific grocery items to the list, spits out the list, and removes what is in the list. Problem not here**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "GroceryList.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace CS151GroceryList;

int main()
{
GroceryList mylist;

/**********************************************************************
* List insertion test                                                *
**********************************************************************/

cout << "Inserting items into the grocery list." << endl << endl;
mylist.insert("Eggs");
mylist.insert("Bananas");
mylist.insert("Wheat Bread");
mylist.insert("Peanut Butter");
mylist.insert("Milk");
mylist.insert("Apples");
mylist.insert("White Bread");

cout << "Finished inserting items." << endl;


cout << "Grocery list contents:" << endl;
mylist.print();

cout << endl << "Finished printing the list." << endl;

/**********************************************************************
* inList test                                                        *
**********************************************************************/

cout << "Testing in list functionality:" << endl;
if (mylist.inList("Oranges"))
{
    cout << "Oranges are on the list." << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Oranges are not on the list." << endl;
}
if (mylist.inList("Apples"))
{
    cout << "Apples are on the list." << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Apples are not on the list." << endl;
}
if (mylist.inList("Peanut Butter"))
{
    cout << "Peanut Butter is on the list." << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Peanut Butter is not on the list." << endl;
}
if (mylist.inList("White Bread"))
{
    cout << "White Bread is on the list." << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "White Bread is not on the list." << endl;
}

/**********************************************************************
* List removal test                                                  *
**********************************************************************/
cout << "Testing list removal." << endl;
cout << endl << "I decided that I didn't want apples after all.  Removing apples." << endl;
mylist.remove("Apples");
cout << "After removing apples, grocery list contents:" << endl;
mylist.print();

cout << endl << "Finished printing the list." << endl << endl;

cout << endl << "I decided that I didn't want white bread either.  Removing white bread." << endl;
mylist.remove("White Bread");
cout << "After removing white bread, grocery list contents:" << endl;
mylist.print();

cout << endl << "Finished printing the list." << endl << endl;

cout << endl << "I'm lactose intolerant, I'd better not get milk.  Removing milk." << endl;
mylist.remove("Milk");
cout << "After removing milk, grocery list contents:" << endl;
mylist.print();

cout << endl << "Finished printing the list." << endl << endl;
}
```

GroceryList.cpp         **The error is in this file**

To be exact the error is in this portion of the code. This is where each function gets called and all the inserting, removing, and checking happens. I have used an_item as a place holder so that I know where I need to figure out the proper value for the function. I have tried all of the pointers I currently have and other values. I even created a temp value(not shown here) but that didn't seem to work either.

```
void GroceryList::insert(const string& an_item)
{

    if (top == an_item.insert)
    {
        return;
    }

    char next;
    while (!empty())
    {
        delete(top);
    }

    if (an_item.insert == NULL)
    {
        top = NULL;
        return;
    }

    ListNodePtr temp = new ListNode;
    temp->item = an_item;
    temp->link = top;

    top = temp;
}
```

Here's the rest of GroceryList.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include "GroceryList.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace CS151GroceryList;

GroceryList::GroceryList() : top(NULL)
{
    //left blank intentionally
 }
GroceryList::~GroceryList()
{
    while (!empty())
    {
        /*remove();*/
        delete top;
    }
}

bool GroceryList::empty()
{
    return(top == NULL);
}

void GroceryList::print()
{
    ListNode*temp = top;
    while (temp != top)
    {
        cout << temp->item << endl;
        temp = temp->link;
    }

    cout << temp->item << endl;
}

void GroceryList::remove(const string& an_item)
{
    if (empty())
    {
        cout << "Error: remove was attempted on empty list.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

}

void GroceryList::insert(const string& an_item)
{

    if (top == temp.insert)
    {
        return;
    }

    char next;
    while (!empty())
    {
        delete(top);
    }

    if (an_item.insert == NULL)
    {
        top = NULL;
        return;
    }

    ListNodePtr temp = new ListNode;
    temp->item = an_item;
    temp->link = top;

    top = temp;
}

bool GroceryList::inList(const string& an_item)
{
    ListNodePtr temp;
    temp = top;
    if (temp == an_item.insert)
    {
        temp = temp->link;
        if (temp != an_item.insert)
        {
            if (temp->link != temp->link)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        /*cout << "Item is in list. Failed to insert." << endl;
        return 1;*/
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Item is not in list. Inserting." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
error C3867:   'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::insert': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::insert' to create a pointer to member
```

I'm pretty sure it is because I am not using the proper value

Comment: What are you trying to do when you use `if (an_item.insert == NULL)`?

Comment: @RSahu That's supposed to be a check if the list has nothing in it while it attempts to insert.

Comment: Not an answer but `#endif GROCERYLIST_H` should be `#endif //GROCERYLIST_H` and an_item.insert should be an_item

Comment: @MohitJain Thanks for pointing that out. Forgot to comment it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have at least these problems in your code:

1)

```
void GroceryList::insert(const string& an_item)
{
    if (top == temp.insert)
    {
        return;
    }
```

if temp is local variable, then you can't use it without declaration (and, for best, proper initialization). Besides, "insert" is member function call, you've missed the braces and argument list, like that "temp.insert(smth)"

2)

```
if (an_item.insert == NULL)
{
    top = NULL;
    return;
}
```

the same issue, you should provide arguments to member call insert. But you don't need insert call there, because an_item argument of GroceryList::insert, passed by const reference, so you can use it without NULL checks

Comment: I thought "ListNodePtr temp" defined temp

Comment: you should define it before using

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks. I will update code here tomorrow as it is late where I am.